# nginx location Regular shorthand

Tags: nginx

I have a lot of code about location, which is very complicated and difficult

```
        location /addressJson/0{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/0;
        }
        location /addressJson/1{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/1;
        }
        location /addressJson/2{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/2;
        }
        location /addressJson/3{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/3;
        }
          location /addressJson/4{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/4;
        }
          location /addressJson/5{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/5;
        }
         location /addressJson/6{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/6;
        }
          location /addressJson/7{
          proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/7;
        }
```

How can I abbreviate?

Comment: You can remove the identical characters from the end of the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements and use just one block: `location /addressJson/ { proxy_pass http://wangzc.wang:1337/; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a *regular expression* `location` to match any URI that begins with the same text. Use a prefix `location`. The `location` that matches all of the locations in your question is:

```
 location /addressJson/ { ... }
```

The optional *uri* part of the `proxy_pass` value performs an aliasing function, which will substitute the *prefix* (specified in the prefix `location`) with the *uri* part in the `proxy_pass` value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location /addressJson/ { 
    proxy_pass http://example.com:1337/;
}
```

If the original requested URI is `/addressJson/foo` then the `/addressJson/` part is removed and the `/` prepended before sending the revised URL as `http://example.com:1337/foo`.

Note that the `location` value should end with `/` in order that the text substitution works correctly.